To check if a relation is a poset or a total order or an equivalence relation.
$F$ is the set of functions defined from $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ to the set $\mathbb{R}_+$ of positive real numbers. $R$ is a relation on $F,$ defined by
$$R=\{(f,g) \mid \exists x_0\in\mathbb{N},\exists c\in\mathbb{R}_+:\forall x\geq x_0,0<f(x) \leq c g(x)\}.$$
I have to check if $R$ is a poset or a total order or an equivalence relation.
My attempt:
$R$ is reflexive for $c=1$.
Anti-symmetric will be again true for c=1.
Transitivity: Again for only one value of $c$, that is for c=1, I can obtain
$fRg$ and $gRh$ $\rightarrow$ $fRh$.
Confused for transitivity property and Total Order property.
How to proceed with the same? Any hint or help will be appreciated.
Did I proceed in a right way?

It's unclear to me what "$R:{(f,g),:, f(x)\le cg(x)}$ for all $x\ge x_0$" means. Could you please write it in the standard notation?

@SassatelliGiulio Edited the question. Is it helpful now?

The string I mentioned is still there, therefore no.

I agree with Sassatelli Giulio, this is unclear. Trying to make sense, it seem to me that $$R={(f,g):\exists c\in\mathbb R^+,;\exists x_0\in\mathbb N_0: x \geq x_0 \implies f(x)\leq cg(x)}.$$ In words, $fRg$ iff there exist positive constants $c \in \mathbb R$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(x)\leq cg(x)$, whenever $x_0\leq x$. Is it so?

If so, consider $f(n)=1$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $g(n)=n+1$. Clearly, $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all $n$, so $(f,g)\in R$; can you find $c$ and $x_0$ such that $g(n)=n+1 \leq c = cf(n)$ for all $n\geq x_0$? I mean, is it really anti-symmetric? (This is supposing my guess in the first comment is OK.)

@amrsa Yeah your first comment is right. Edited my question again.

Hi, Priya. I've edited your post so that the relation will be clear. What you've currently got doesn't actually show us how you went about your proof attempts, which makes it very difficult for us to gauge your experience level and understanding of the definitions. Could you please add that work in, so we don't waste your time (telling you things you already know) and our time (figuring out the hard way that there are some concepts you don't know)?

@amrsa it looks like your hint comment has more to do with whether $R$ is symmetric, rather than antisymmetric.

@CameronBuie Yes, you're right, of course. Meanwhile, it seems clear the relation is not anti-symmetric either. For example, if $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=2n+1$, then $fRg$ with $c=1$, and $gRf$ with $c=2$.
